# Reloading the model in the view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net5

I have a **google map** that loads with markers and a route at the beginning. (**MVC** in .NET5)

The position of the markers changes every few seconds (it is saved on the server, the data comes from the mobile application)

I would like to download new data from the server every few seconds and update the view. (I mean refresh the data without reloading the page)

I did this by asking GET to REST in JavaScript every 5 seconds, but is it possible to do it differently?

If and how to update the **model** in the **view** to receive new data every now and then?

*In the internet I find partially reloading views, but I only want to refresh the data (coordinates and other data)*

Comment: Why not to update markers with javascript? Make ajax request every 5 sec and reload markers on map.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you look into [Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and using [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=webassembly) for this, if possible. Using WebSockets to listen for changes is going to be so much more efficient and cleaner than having an ajax call every 5 seconds.